# Vectors and classes

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have the following two classes:
the first one

```
class node{
public:
   node(); //default constructor 
   node(const node&);//copy constructor
   ~node(); //destructor
   node& operator= (const node&);

   short visits;
   bool inizpc;
   cards cards_first;
   cards cards_second;
   cards * first; //cards is another class, don't mind that
   cards * second;
   int * suits;
   node * children;
    //other members
}
```

and the class

```
class tree{
public:
    tree() : //initialization list {branch.reserve(20)};//constructor
    tree(const tree&); //copy constructor
    ~tree();//destructor
    tree& operator= (const tree&);

    std::vector<node> branch;
    //other members

    void tries(node&);
}
```

My problem arise when i try to use the branch vector, in particular when i use the .push_back() function inside the following function

```
 void tree::tries(node& a){
    a.visits++;
    branch.push_back(a);
 }
```

the compiler just terminate the function without running it. The problem is the `branch.push_back` but I've not used vectors much so I don't get where the error stand and what i'm missing. Also, how does push_back allocate the object i pass? Does it call the copy constructor?

EDIT: It seems my problem is in the destructor

```
~node(){
 cout << "deleting node\n";
 delete[] first;
 delete[] second;
 delete[] suits;
 delete[] children;
 }
```

I tried doing something like

```
node a;
a.visits=1;
cout << a.visits;
```

commenting out the destructor definition and declaration it works fine. Is there a reason for it to be deleted before execution ends?

also, here the default constructor, copy constructor and copy assignement definitions, the destructor is as defined above

```
//default constructor
node::node():
                    visits(0),
                    inizpc(false)
                    cards_first(0,0);//cards have a parameter ctor
                    cards_second(0,0);
{
    first=new carte[10];
    second=new carte[10];
    suits=new short[4];
    children=new node[visits];
}


//copy constructor
node::node(node& a){
    visits=a.visits;
    inizpc=a.inizpc;
    cards_first=a.cards_first;
    cards_second=a.cards_second;

    first=new cards[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) first[i]=a.first[i];

    second=new cards[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) second[i]=a.second[i];

    suits=new int[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) suits[i]=a.suits[i];

    children=new node[a.visits];
    for (int i=0; i<a.visits; i++) children[i]=a.children[i];
}


//assignement
node& node::operator= (node& a){
    visits=a.visits;
    inizpc=a.inizpc;
    cards_first=a.cards_first;
    cards_second=a.cards_second;

    delete[] first;
    first=new cards[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) first[i]=a.first[i];

    delete[] second;
    second=new cards[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) second[i]=a.second[i];

    delete[] suits;
    suits=new int[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) suits[i]=a.suits[i];

    delete[] children;
    children=new node[a.visits];
    for (int i=0; i<a.visits; i++) children[i]=a.children[i];
}
```

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere in the code you didn't post

Comment: Yes, push_back calls the copy-ctor. Check out the docs at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back or experiment with it.

Comment: Since you're using `vector<node>`, you need to post the copy constructor, assignment, op and destructor.  If those functions are faulty, then calling `push_back` on `node` objects will not work correctly.

Comment: doing it in a moment

Comment: @luigi There is nothing wrong with the destructor.  Please post your copy constructor and assignment operator.  The destructor is where things finally break down, but is not where the bad things start to happen.  Also do **not** comment it out.  It is telling you something fundamental is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the various definitons. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Your assignment operator is supposed to return a reference, but doesn't return a value.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie haven't noticed that... sorry for the mess. It work fine. Can I ask, why the assignment operator is required to use  the vector?

Comment: Use some smart pointers in the ctor (if you must use pointers). All those `new`s  and assignments in the ctor may throw and they you're leaking like crazy. Raw `new` and `delete` are a sign of danger.

Comment: @PSkocik Yes i guess that's not the best, but I haven't still studied those unfortunately. Thanks for the help

Comment: @luigi Whether or not it is used in the vector, it can be used elsewhere, places where you did not expect.  You must write it correctly -- you cannot get away with having a faulty, fundamental function like an assignment operator -- it is like a ticking time bomb.  See my answer.

Comment: Then you should do something like `try{     for(int i=0; i<10; i++) first[i]=a.first[i];      second=new cards[10];
 }catch(...){ delete [] first; throw; }` then another try block where you delete both first and second in the catch clause and rethrow, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't have an assignment operator, as `operator =` is not defined.  You're missing that one function.  But my point still remains -- you should write it, as any assignment being done will not work correctly without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you posted your copy constructor, destructor, your assignment operator was not implemented.  Instead you posted something that looked like a combination of a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

In your original post, you really did not implement an assignment operator.  I don't know if you hastily posted your class and just plain forgot to post it, but in any event, you need this function to complete the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

As my comment also suggested, a lack of an assignment operator for a class such as `node` will bite you at some point, either now or later -- you can't avoid it.

To correctly write the assignment operator, using the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) is the easiest thing to do, given you have a copy constructor and destructor that seem to be doing things correctly:

```
#include <algorithm>

node& operator=(const node& a)
{
    node temp(a);
    std::swap(temp.visits, visits);
    std::swap(temp.inizpc, initzpc);
    std::swap(temp.cards_first, cards_first);
    std::swap(temp.cards_second, cards_second);
    std::swap(temp.first, first);
    std::swap(temp.second, second);
    std::swap(temp.suits, suits);
    std::swap(temp.children, children);
    return *this;
}
```

All we did was create a temporary, swapped out the internals of the current object with the temporary, and let the temporary die at the end with the old data.  Also note that a reference is returned.

This technique only works if the copy constructor and destructor are flawless, and that the copy constructor does **not** use the assignment operator as a helper function (as unfortunately, a few C++ programmers seem to insist on doing).  Again, glancing at your code, it seems these two functions were written correctly, so copy / swap for the assignment operator would be the best way to complete the job.

After you do this, you should thoroughly test the `node` class in a simple `main` program.  You don't need `std::vector` to test whether your class has correct copy semantics:

```
int main()
{
   node n1;
   // assume that n1 has been populated with some data
   //...
   node n2 = n1;
   node n3;
   n3 = n1;
}
```

That one small `main` function tests copy construction, assignment, and destruction.  If there is anything faulty, a program such as above will be faulty.  The program above should be able to be run from beginning to end with no memory errors, no memory leaks, no double-deallocations, etc.

In addition, your `tree` class does not need a destructor, assignment operator, or copy constructor.  You should remove them, since `tree` has all members that are safely copyable (the `node` class can now be copied without error, given that it would now have correct copy semantics).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The class `tree` needs a destructor too since it has another member which is a pointer to node. I forgot to post it, sorry but it was late night when i posted

Comment: and this explains too why the last function definiton was of a copy constructor instead of an assignment. I edited that